# Direct link to "New post" in specific category?

Tags: posts, categories, links

How can i create a direct link to "New post" (/post-new.php), which will create a new post automatically added in specific category?

In other words, i click on the link "new post in category one", then browser opens WP editor, where category "one" is already selected.

Maybe i can somehow do it with information from the URL? Something like this: "/post-new.php?postcategory=one".
Don't know is it possible to do.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Paste the following code into your `functions.php` file. The `wp_terms_checklist_args` filter hook will make sure that one or more category is pre-selected and the `op_create_selected_cat_post_link()` function will help you to create a new post link with pre-selected category ids. The function takes `$cats` parameter and it can be a single category id or multiple categories ids. You can also pass the link text. The function also checks user login status and user capability.

```
add_filter( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', function( $args ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && 'post-new.php' === $pagenow && isset( $_GET['cat'] ) ) {
        $cat = array();
        if ( is_array( $_GET['cat'] ) ) {
            $cat = array_filter( $_GET['cat'], 'absint' );
        } else {
            $cat = (array) absint( $_GET['cat'] );
        }
        $args['selected_cats'] = $cat;
    }
    return $args;
} );

/**
 * Create a new post link with preselected category
 *
 * @param int|array $cats Preselected category id
 * @return void
 */
function op_create_selected_cat_post_link( $cats, $text = 'Create a new post' ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $url = admin_url( add_query_arg(
        array(
            'cat' => $cats,
        ),
        'post-new.php'
    ) );

    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '">' . esc_html( $text ) . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Can you please post same sample link url? I can not get it preselect categories.

Comment: @LeeGee I didn't find any deprecated notice in the source. Where did you find that it's been deprecated?

Comment: @obiPlabon - My bad: it *is* called by `wp_terms_checklist` despite the note in the Codex saying it is deprecated. Must be another reason this code was ineffective for me.